# Redirect from PHP isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page displaying bootstrp-slider.  It works fine except for going to a particular page when clicked on the slider picture.

Main php: bootstrao-slider.php

There is a div in this:

```
$d.='
div>
  <img u="image" src="../images/'.$sliderskin.'">
  <div u="caption" t="NO" t3="RTT|2" r3="137.5%" du3="3000" d3="500"
       style="position:absolute;width:900px;height:420px;top:30px;left:550px;">
  <a href="hooks/slider-home.php"><img src="../images/'.$picture.'"
       style="position:absolute;width:700px;height:340px;top:0px;left:0px;"></a>
  </div>  

  <div style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:120px;top:15px;left:30px;
       padding:5px;text-align:left;line-height:45px;font-size:30px;
       font-weight:700;color:<?php echo $labelcolour;?>">
       '.$label1.'<br>'.$label2.'<br>'.$label3.'<br>'.$label4.'<br>'.$label5.'
       <br>'.$label6.'<br>'.$label7.'<br>'.$label8.'<br>
  </div>
</div>';
```

The "hooks/slider-home.php" does few things and tries to go to another page.  Code is:

```
if ($callfunc == 'Renting'){
    // ...
    header('location:../RENTINGT_view.php?selectedID='.$itemid);
}

if ($callfunc == 'Rent-to-Own'){
    // ...
    header('location:../RENTTOOWNT_view.php?selectedID='.$itemid);
}

header('location:../index.php');
```

The first 2 redirect calls

```
header('location:../RENTINGT_view.php?selectedID='.$itemid);
```

and

```
header('location:../RENTTOOWNT_view.php?selectedID='.$itemid);
```

are not working, while the last one works.  I could not understand why its happening so.

If someone can help me to solve this issue, I can send the full codes or show what happens, through Team Viewer.

Comment: Why can't you wrap each slide in an anchor link instead?

Comment: please don't post an email/skype address in a question. We're not a "code to email" service. I removed it in an edit.

Comment: You have a missing `<` it should be `$d.='
<div>` also what are all these dashes and asterisks?? `----- ***`

Comment: A few things: (1) Do you have a `die()` or `exit()` statement after each `header()` call? If not, the code will continue running and will end up calling the last `header()` no matter what. Once you do a `header('location')`, you should usually also stop the program running any further. (2) Are you sure that the code is getting to the `header()` calls that you think it is? Have you confirmed that? It could be something wrong in the `----` lines or `$callfunc` could be set different to how you expect. Check those points as well; don't just assume that it's the `header()` call that is at fault.